# compare/sort prices and push text prices to the bottom of results - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I'm using wordpress. Some of products prices are not numerical and they are like P.O.R. (price on request). I have a filter which sorts prices "low to high" and "high to low". Below you can see my sorting code:

**LOW TO HIGH**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_key' => 'product_price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
$post_list = get_posts($args);
```

**HIGH TO LOW**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_key' => 'product_price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
$post_list = get_posts($args);
```

Above code works how it was supposed to. When string is being compared to an integer, it is treated as 0 and that's why in first case (low to high) products with P.O.R. are on top and in second case (high to low) they are on bottom. But I want P.O.R. items to be always at the bottom. Researched many things but didn't found solution to this. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be exclude the POR's from the **low to high** query and write an additional query that just queries the POR products, and then merge it with the **low to high** query. To exclude the POR's from the query, you could add a meta_compare

```
$nonpor = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_key' => 'product_price',
    'meta_value_num'   => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '>'
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
```

This will get you a list of all the posts that have prices, without the POR's: Next we query them:

```
$por = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_key' => 'product_price',
    'meta_value_num'   => '0',
    'meta_compare' => '='
    'posts_per_page'=> -1
);
```

Now we merge the results:

```
$regular = new WP_Query( $nonpor );
$pors = new WP_Query( $por );

//create a new, blank query object
$combined = new WP_Query(); 

// put the combined data into the new query
$combined->posts = array_merge( $regular->posts, $pors->posts );

//set the post count if you need it
$result->post_count = count( $result->posts );
//finally get the post list
$post_list = $combined->posts;
```

Replace this with your LOW TO HIGH, and you should be good.

Comment: Yes the idea is simple and good one. But it is not working how we want as `'meta_value_num'   => '0',` is not taking 'por' items as actually por item's price is just P.O.R. and not 0. Any ideas?

Comment: You wrote in your question that when a string is being compared to an integer, it is treated as zero. Are you sure it's not treated as a 1? In that case you could just change it to 'meta_value_num' => '1'.

If that is not working, something like `'meta_value' => 'P.O.R.', 'meta_compare' => '!='` for the first query and `'meta_value' => 'P.O.R.','meta_compare' => '='` for the second should work. Let me know :)